# Получить подъезды жилого дома

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Можно ли получить подъезды жилого дома как это делаеет yandex.ru/maps:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну раз кто-то делает, то можно.

Comment: Во внешнем API нет информации о подъездах и входах.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы знаете, что здание на карте Яндекс имеет размеченные подъезды, вы можете узнать их координаты через соответствующий запрос к [геокодеру](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geocoder/). Например, запросив адрес ***"Россия, Москва, улица Введенского, 5к1, подъезд 1"*** геокодер отдаст его координаты, а тип **"kind"** объекта будет **"entrance"**.

Но запросить просто адрес или координаты с типом kind=entrance для поиска всех подъездов в настоящее время нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

В базе ГАР (форк ФИАС и КЛАДР) есть информация не только о подъездах, но еще этажах и квартирах. Сделайте нужную вам выборку, остальное удалите. Получайте обновления автоматически.

[Сведения о составе информации Государственного адресного реестра](https://fias.nalog.ru/docs/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0.zip)

[XSD схемы выгрузки БД в формате ГАР](https://fias.nalog.ru/docs/gar_schemas.zip)

[Описание службы получения обновлений](https://fias.nalog.ru/docs/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9.doc)

[Ссылка на полную БД ГАР на 31.12.2021](https://fias-file.nalog.ru/downloads/2021.12.31/gar_xml.zip) [32Гб]

Для ленивых есть проприетарный API: https://kladr-api.ru/